# Specify AWS EMR Security configuration from AWS template , lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, emr, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a EMR cluster through cloud formation . 
I have already created security configuration from AWS management console .
I am not able to find any way where i can add this security config while creating EMR from cloud formation.

Alternatively i can leverage lambda function , but how to add a EMR security configuration after cluster is created ?

any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible with cloudformation.  Security Configurations were released September of last year and Cloudformation has yet to support it.  At this time the only way would be to do it manually after the creation or via the lambda or other method.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, this is only possible using Lambda backed custom resources. This is what you'll need to do on a high-level:

1. Create EMR cluster using CloudFormation supported `AWS::EMR::Cluster` resource type.
2. Define a Lambda backed custom resource, say with resource type `Custom::EMRSecurityConfiguration`.
3. Define a Lambda function that'll be used in step #2 and do the needful by using AWS SDK (*e.g.* `boto3` if you're writing your Lambda in Python) and actually create/update/delete the security configuration based on the kind of EventType (the value for this will be passed in by CloudFormation to your function).

Lambda function defined in #3 will be triggered by CloudFormation everytime you create/update/delete the custom resource defined in #2. I'd recommend looking at AWS docs for [Lambda-backed custom resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) and [security configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-encryption-enable-security-configuration.html#emr-encryption-creating-configuration).